# Desabilitar todos os inputs de um form utilizando apenas css?

Tags: css, css3

**Problema**

Estou implementado alguns controles em um protótipo, e estou criando um painel *overlay* para representar processamentos em background, carregamento de *asserts* do servidor, busca de dados no servidor, enfim para representar que o sistema está trabalhando e o usuário deve aguardar.

Para isso estou criando uma `div` sobre toda aplicação, com um `z-index` maior do que o conteúdo que desejo deixar imutável para o cliente, enquanto ele aguarda o processo. Mas verifiquei que mesmo com a `div` sobre o conteúdo é possível acessa-lo através de <kbd>tab</kbd>, como podem ver [aqui no exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/1vf7tefb/2/).

Então gostaria de alguma forma de desabilitar os inputs ou evitar o acesso a ele através de <kbd>tab</kbd>, mas isso utilizando apenas `css` (javascript não é viável), algo nesse sentido:

```css
form.disabled input {
    /*  o que procuro é algo assim: */
    disabled: disabled; /* isso não funciona e nem existe no css, é só para exemplificar o que pretendo */
    /* como desabilitar todos os inputs deste form com css, sem usar javascript? */
    /* ou no minimo como não permitir da o foco no inputs quando o form estiver desabilitado */
}
```

**Pergunta?**

Há alguma forma via `css` de desabilitar um `input` html?

Comment: Não existe forma de desativar um input via CSS. Você terá que, ou setar o atributo no elemento, ou "simular" um disabled com `background-color` e `cursor`

Comment: `"javascript não é viável"` eu sinto a sua dor.

Comment: @Beterraba, viu o meu exemplo, o que pretendo é não deixar o usuário interagir com o formulário, enquanto o overlay está sendo exibido e o form com a class `disabled`

Comment: Vi sim. Entendi o problema do tab, apenas ressaltei que não é possível (e nem deveria ser).

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível bloquear o acesso aos inputs apenas com CSS.

O que você pode fazer é simular este bloqueio, de forma que o usuário entenda que o input não deva ser utilizado, exemplo:

```
form.disabled input{
    pointer-events:none;
    outline:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/y0zjqnzd/)**

O problema desta "simulação" é que ao pressionar <kbd>tab</kbd> o usuário ainda acaba selecionando o campo "desabilitado", o que poderia causar confusão. Fora isso ainda tem o problema de o campo ainda aceitar valores, ou seja, se eu apertar <kbd>tab</kbd> e começar a escrever nele, mesmo sem mostrar ele ainda aceitaria o que eu escrevesse.

Comment: Pois é, até é boa sua colocação, e talvez será útil, mas o problema de ele mexer sem querer ainda existe, não pretendo usar javascript para isso pois estou trabalhando com angular.js e gostaria apenas de setar a variável de contexto loading, por exemplo e o form já desabilitar e o loading subir, mesmo assim vou procurar outras alternativas. Obrigado pela alternativa, e esclarecimento.

Comment: @Fernando Se o seu objetivo é bloquear a tela inteira enquanto carrega alguma informação, uma outra solução interessante seria criar uma `div` por cima de tudo, de forma a bloquear as ações do usuário até o carregamento ser completo.

Comment: Mas é isso que estou fazendo acompanhe meu [exemplo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/1vf7tefb/2/), mas mesmo assim o form continua podendo ser acessado.

Comment: que tal desabilitar o botão tab quando a div surgir?

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, What? Como assim desabilitar o tab?

Comment: editei minha resposta abaixo, é um POG, mas não vejo melhor solução rs

Answer (score 1):

Unico ponto a acrescentar aos comentários acima é que, caso o usuário tenha qualquer debugador, ele consegue reabilitar os campos do formulário.... pelo menos o suficiente pra editar o conteúdo.. e assim talvez enviar o formulário..

Uma possivel solução seria modificar o `imput="text"` por um `label` com a informação, mas acho que isso teria que ser bem ardiloso

Sem contar os diversos navegadores onde cada um aceita uma quantidade limitada de atributos que por sua vez é diferente dos outros.... ai a coisa começa a embaçar pro lado do programador

Meio que não se trabalha muito com a hipótese de que o usuário tenha conhecimento o suficiente  para saber desses paranaue de `HTML/JS/CSS`.. então o que podemos fazer é disfarçar mesmo...

**-----EDIT--------**

testa isso pra bloquear o tab:

```
function teste(evt){
    tecla = evt.keyCode;
    if (tecla==9) {$("#aa").focus();}
}
```

e coloca isso no `form`:

```
<form id="esse" onkeypress="teste(event)">
```

o primeiro campo do formulario eu coloquei o id 'aa' pra receber o focus, ai é como se ele entendesse que o tab voltou pro indice 0, e toda vez que ele digita tab, ele adiciona 1 ao indice, e retira 1 do indice.

Ai quando o formulário for bloqueado voce remove o evento teste(event) do form, quando o formulario for desbloqueado, adiciona o evento teste(event).

Enfim, é uma grande gambiarra, mas é a melhor solução que encontrei rs

Comment: Entendi sua ideia, é uma alternativa, criei uma alternativa também que evita a entrada com o focus nos `input`, acompanhe [aqui minha solução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30603/2998).

Answer (score 0):

Desenvolvi uma solução (type == **POG**), que resolveu meu problema em particular, e só irá funcionar se for utilizado com uma `div` *overlay* sobre o conteúdo que não permita a manipulação direta do usuário com o formulário, minha solução evita a entrada do `focus` no `inputs` filhos de um formulário com a `class = disabled`. Além do focus, também estou manipulando os eventos de `mousedown click change` e tentando os cancelar. Segue minha solução:

```js
$('body').on('focus mousedown click change', 'form.disabled input', function(e){
    // cancel stack events
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    // remove focus
    $(this).blur();

    return false;
});
```

Infelizmente tive que utilizar javascript.

Acompanhe o [exemplo online de minha solução](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/1d0wz58v/3/).

> Obs: Essa não é uma solução definitiva, nem perto disso, é a solução para o meu problema em particular, e continuo aguardando uma solução mais eficiente.

Comment: Campeão, outra cosia que eu já havia me esquecido, é da possibilidade de voce colocar um tabindex="-1" em todos os campos do formulário quando voce bloquear ele! Ai o tab não vai entrar no formulário